# Base64 decoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, byte, codec

I'm trying to decode some text in base 64, and I don't understand why I get an error while trying to do that:

`b'Zm9v'.decode('base64_codec')`

The exception raised is: `TypeError: expected bytes, not memoryview`

PS: I know there's an alternative using the `base64` module. But I'm interested in knowing the answer, just out of curiosity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `bytes.decode()` and `str.encode()` methods (rightly) only support codecs that also convert between types; `bytes.decode()` must *always* return a `str` object, while `str.encode()` must return `bytes`; see the [original issue that introduced these codecs](http://bugs.python.org/issue7475):

> Codecs can work with arbitrary types, it's just that the helper methods on unicode and bytes objects only support one combination of types in Python 3.x.

So the specific error you see is caused by the fact that the `bytes.decode()` method always expects to return a value of type `str`. Similarly, the `str.encode()` method balks at codecs that do not return `bytes` as a return value:

```
>>> 'Ceasar'.encode('rot_13')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: encoder did not return a bytes object (type=str)
```

As such, for bytes-to-bytes and str-to-str codecs, you need to use the `codecs` module directly:

```
import codecs

codecs.getdecoder('base64_codec')(b'Zm9v')[0]
```